# Dynamically compare list for common occurrences

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to dynamically use sets to find common entires in lists. If I have a list of list that could contain any number of lists how can I go about find all the common occurrences in all the lists.  I have thought about enumerating the list and storing each nested list in its own variable but then I am not sure how to compare all the individual lists.

#### Example of List:

```
l = [[1,2,3,4,], [3,6,4,2,1], [6,4,2,6,7,3]]
```

I want to do something like this but dynamic so it can accept any number of lists:

```
common = set(l[0]) & set(l[1]) & set(l[2])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reduce`, with a `lambda` for

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3,4,], [3,6,4,2,1], [6,4,2,6,7,3]]
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> common = reduce(lambda l1,l2: set(l1) & set(l2), l)
>>> print(common)
{2, 3, 4}
```

Or, as a slightly modified version of @tobias_k's solution (as pointed in the comment), you can do it without lambda as

```
>>> common = reduce(set.intersection, [set(l[0])] + l[1:]))
```

Comment: Without `lambda`: `reduce(set.intersection, map(set, l))`

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer

Comment: reduce with map will have twice the order of reduce with lambda. So I would prefer reduce with lambda ie reduce+map = O(2n) while reduce+lambda = O(n) assuming set intersection is O(1)

Comment: @Onyambu Do you have a reference for this? The way I see it, `map` will convert each element of `l` to `set` _once_, whereas OP's original lambda will convert each element to `set` each time in the lambda; in particular, `l1` will already be a `set` for each but the first element, but `set` is called again, creating a new set. Also, `set.intersection` is certainly not O(1) if the set has more than one element, is it? IPython's `%timeit` shows that `map` is a bit faster (about 10%).

Comment: BTW, I think you meant `[set(l[0])] + l[1:]` (note the additional `[...]`)?

Comment: @tobias_k, `map` has order n, since it will iterate through all the elements of the list to make them a set. then reduce will also iterate to intersect the two sets. Now what if I just change the code abit? so that I may use intersection also. ie: `reduce(lambda x,y:set.intersection(set(y),x),l)`, here we just have one set function. This does the set and intersects at the same time. This is your map, written in lambda. This has lower order than the reduce+map. For this answer, if we take Order of set.intersection==order of set, then it also has lower order than reduce+map

Comment: @tobias_k the difference in speed is due to the call of lambda severally. I cant get the source right now. I am sorry. will look for it. What I can try and request you to do is to write out the two in explicit for loops, ie.. reduce+lambda with just one for loop and then reduce+map with two for-loops.. Then you will see the difference in the two

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, reduce and map will iterate the list twice, but this does not mean that it takes longer. As I said, the total calls to `set` is _higher_ using the lambda, i.e. even though it loops just once, it does more work in each iteration of the loop. `reduce` with `map` calls both `set` and `intersection` n times (as does the variant from your comment, but in a more complicated way), whereas the original apprach calls `intersection` n times and `set` 2n times.

Comment: @Onyambu.. Yes.. I meant `[set(l[0])] + l[1:]`. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @tobias_k I see what you mean. I did not know the order of set or set intersection. Although just from cutiosity is that also similar to the code i provided?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set.intersection`:

```
set.intersection(*(set(ls) for ls in l)) #evaluates to {2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: Out of the answers given, this seems to be the best theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` from `functools` package:

```
from functools import reduce

l = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 6, 4, 2, 1], [6, 4, 2, 6, 7, 3]]

print(reduce(set.intersection, map(set, l)))
```

**Output**:

```
{2, 3, 4}
```